# IE7, IE8 sliding doors buttons active state is not working

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, sliding-doors

I have buttons in different sizes and different colours in one sprite, using sliding doors technique, everything is fine in all major browsers but, when I am trying to run this in IE7, IE8 , everything seems fine, except :active state, it only works in the right corner of the button. Any suggestions ? url: http://www.dmitree.com/temp/cb/buttons2/buttons2.html

Answer (score 0):

Inside anchor class"button" you have span. you have applied height as well as line height properties on this span. I guess If you remove height and only keep line height will resolve your issue.

but Please check in other browsers too. as removing height for IE may or may not affect other browsers.

additional resource: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/make-fancy-buttons-using-css-sliding-doors-technique/

hope this helps